# My image cache not working with large images. Why?

Tags: swift, swift5

My image cache is not working with large images. This is how my image cache code looks like. I'm caching my image in a dictionary instead of using NSCache.

```
var n = 0
var imageCache = [String: UIImage]()

//MARK: - UIImageView
extension UIImageView {

  func downloadImage(from urlString: String) {
    let newString = "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/c0/1e/1d/c01e1d10ad929eab6d7f6c8b39c970df.jpg"

    if let cachedImage = imageCache[urlString] {
        print("Geting image from cache")
        self.image = cachedImage
        return
    }

    guard let url = URL(string: newString) else { return }
    
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        if let err = error {
            print(err.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            guard let data = data else { return }
            let image = UIImage(data: data)
            n += 1
            print(n)
            imageCache[urlString] = image
            self.image = image
        }
    }
    .resume()
  }
}
```

The newString is a url to a large image file. Now the problem is this is getting called multiple times. I have a table view that contains messages from users, which I'm fetching from Firestore. This is how my Message & MessageCell file look like.

```
struct Message: {
  var text: String
  var timeStamp = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
  var createdBy: String
  var createdByProfileImageUrl: String
}


class MessageCell: UITableViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var userImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var messageTextLabel: UILabel!

  var message: Message? {
    didSet {
        updateUI()
    }
  }

  private func updateUI() {
    guard let message = message else { return }

    messageTextLabel.text = message.text  
    userImageView.downloadImage(from: message.createdByProfileImageUrl)
  }
    
}
```

As of now I only have 3 users with 19 messages in my Firestore database. I'm expecting that downloadImage func URLSession to only run 3 times. Since the messages only have 3 possible user profile images urls, which I'm trying to save to my imageCache. However the URLSession is running 15 time, I know this because of N. I really don't know why this is happening. The only thing I can think of is that the image file is really large, the newString URL is an 8k image. This is what gets printed out on my console when I run the project and I start to scroll my tableView.

[image]

Now how would I be able to fix this problem. Would really appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Make the image optional in the dictionary and add the key to the dictionary just before you start the download and set the image once it’s downloaded in the cache . Don’t forget to remove the key if you get an error

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Okay so I switch my dictionary to [String: UIImage?] and I added this code just above the URLSession imageCache[urlString] = nil as UIImage?  This made it only run 3 times as excepted but now it cause another problem. Since the tableView has more than one message from the same user the first message has the user image but the other messages from the user their imageView is empty. I have to scroll down  and scroll back up to see the image for the message.

Comment: Yes that is a problem you need to deal with when you have an asynchronous design like this. Perhaps you should look into using local notifications.